# Django Viewflow: From where to send email to user on task assignment?

Tags: django, django-viewflow

I need to email owner when task is assigned to them. I tried following ways:

1. `Assign` accepts a callable function which should return task owner. We can send email in this callable function. But if you read source code, you will find that this callable method is called multiple times, by `calc_owner` function. Hence if we email user here, multiple emails will be send
2. Create a new Node method like `EmailUser` and call it after `Assign` and before `Next`. But the issue is, it should also be thorough some callable like `Assign` for it to be called for each `Process`. But where to call this callable function

This seems like very general use-case, with a very difficult solution. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality could be achieved in a custom subclass of flow.View, with custom activation class, where you can extend `create_task` method:

https://github.com/viewflow/viewflow/blob/master/viewflow/flow/activation.py#L77

```
approve = (
    UserTask(view.MyView)
    .onCreateEmail(template='...', recipients=....)
    .onAutoAssignEmail(template='...')
```

)

Comment: How does the `onCreateEmail` reference to the same user that gets randomly chosen using `Assign(lambda act: random(user))`?

Comment: OK I worked it out by overwriting the `calc_owner` to add extra code to send out the  email.

Comment: The correct way is to implement custom activation class with overridden activate method. Flow class node stands for declarative node definition only